# How to replace AC/DC adapter but keep old connector

Tags: wire, splicing, adapter

I have an AC/DC adapter I need to replace for my dehumidifier.  The whole system is no longer working, and I am confident the problem is with the adapter.

Finding the correct adapter is easy enough; there are many 12 V, 6 A options out there.  The problem is though that none of them that I have seen have the correct connector to plug in to the dehumidifier.  See pictures below.

How would I go about splicing the current connector in to a new adapter?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Chop and solder. Of course, if the current adapter is dead, it can be difficult to establish correct polarity - but I think I see that labeled nicely on the present adapter (it's not always, though it should be.)

For a tidy job, split the cords and cut the + and - wires at different lengths (so the joints are slightly offset, rather than being at the same point) slip a large heat shrink over the whole cable and one or two smaller heat shrinks over the individual wires, moving them far enough from the joint not to be shrunk when soldering. If the offset is large enough you can skip the inner ones entirely and just have the outer one (the offset keeps the exposed joints from touching each other when held by the outer heat shrink.)

Comment: Exactly what I do. Also consider wrapping just one of the wires with the inner tubing.